# Check if timestamp coming from DB is 2hrs ago or older

Tags: java, spring

I want to compare a timestamp coming from db and see if it's 1 hr 59 minutes old or not,I have implemented the following code.Please review it and suggest changes:

```
  private static final long TIME_LIMIT= 7199 * 1000;

    private Token getTokenFromDB ()
        {
            InterfaceRequestResponseDAO.getInstance ().getEntityManager ().createNamedQuery (InterfaceRequestResponse.Queries.GET_TOKEN) //
                    .setParameter ("token", InterfaceRequestResponse.COL_RESPONSEEND)//
                    .setParameter ("interfaceRequestResponseID", this.getInterfaceRequestResponseID ())//
                    .executeUpdate ();
            // authenticationToken.getResponseEnd ();
            long responseEnd = System.currentTimeMillis ();
            if (responseEnd < TIME_LIMIT)
                return authenticationToken;
            else
                return NOT_VALID;
```

Comment: I suggest you to use [`JodaDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html).

Comment: how can u plz suggest a bit in detail?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [`JodaDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)..

I implemented the same thing in a project. What I did was I saved the expire time instead of the timestamp created. This makes it more easy to handle.

Everytime I refresh the token, I update the `expireTime` by adding the `offset`

```
DateTime expireTime = new DateTime(new Date());

expireTime = expireTime.addHours(2);//because token expires in 2 hours
```

And then I store this time.

When I'm requesting, I used to check if the current time < expire time.

```
DateTime expireTime = getTimeFromDB();

DateTime now = new DateTime(new Date());

if( now.isBefore(expireTime))
{
 //valid token.
}
else
{
// refresh your token and update the time.
}
```